# Sequelize and node v0.6.1

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Im implementing a script with use Sequelize ORM for Node. Im using node 0.6.1 but when I execute the script, the following log is displayed:

The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.

Sequelize supports version 0.6.1 of nodE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current version should work well with node 0.6.0. thewarnings will be resolved in the next release